# Vue 3 SPA. Select emits lang and contentStore DOESN'T renew content ONLY in mobile devices

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, html-select, pinia

Vue 3 SPA on Vite 4.2 and TypeScript 5.02.

Select on click emits lang.value and in the parent component App.vue contentStore should renew content. A typical thing that works perfect on my Linux Ubuntu desktop. Works equally perfect in Firefox and Chrome devtools, also when I simulate any mobile device - iOS or Android.
HOWEVER, when deployed on Hostinger, it doesn't switch languages on any Android or iOS device. You can see here https://rybnikov.online.

Here is my App.vue:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { RouterView } from 'vue-router'
import { useWindowSize } from '@vueuse/core'
import { ref, defineAsyncComponent, onUpdated } from 'vue'
import { useContentStore } from './stores/content'
import socialMedia from './data/social.json'

const contentStore = useContentStore()
const lang = ref(localStorage.getItem('lang') || navigator.language.slice(0, 2))
const social = Object.assign(socialMedia)
const LayoutDesktop = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/layouts/LayoutDesktop.vue'))
const LayoutMobile = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/layouts/LayoutMobile.vue'))
const NavigationDesktop = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/NavigationDesktop.vue'))
const NavigationMobile = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/NavigationMobile.vue'))
const BodyMobile = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/BodyMobile.vue'))
const FooterMobile = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/FooterMobile.vue'))
const FooterDesktop = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/FooterDesktop.vue'))
const { width } = useWindowSize()
const setLang = (newLang: string) => {
  lang.value = newLang
  localStorage.setItem('lang', lang.value)
  contentStore.setContent(lang.value)
}
onUpdated(() => {
  contentStore.setContent(lang.value)
  contentStore.getContent
})
</script>

<template>
  <LayoutMobile v-if="width < 769">
    <template #header>
      <NavigationMobile @changeLang="setLang" />
    </template>
    <template #default>
      <BodyMobile :content="contentStore.getContent" />
    </template>
    <template #footer>
      <FooterMobile :lang="lang" :social="social" />
    </template>
  </LayoutMobile>
  <LayoutDesktop v-else>
    <template #header>
      <NavigationDesktop @changeLang="setLang" />
    </template>
    <template #asideLeft>
      <h1></h1>
    </template>
    <template #default>
      <RouterView :content="contentStore.getContent" />
    </template>
    <template #asideRight>
      <h1></h1>
    </template>
    <template #footer>
      <FooterDesktop :lang="lang" :social="social" />
    </template>
  </LayoutDesktop>
</template>
```

Here is my NavigationLanguageSelect.vue

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import langSelection from '@/data/lang.json'

const emit = defineEmits<{ (e: 'changeLang', lang: string): void }>()
const langs = Object.assign(langSelection)
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <select class="p-1 text-sm rounded-lg text-gray-700">
      <option
        class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100"
        v-for="language in langs"
        :key="language.text"
        @click="emit('changeLang', language.value)"
        @select="emit('changeLang', language.value)"
      >
        {{ language.flag }} {{ language.text }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is package.json

```json
{
  "name": "oleg",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "run-p type-check build-only",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "build-only": "vite build",
    "type-check": "vue-tsc --noEmit",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .vue,.js,.jsx,.cjs,.mjs,.ts,.tsx,.cts,.mts --fix --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "format": "prettier --write src/"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vueuse/core": "^9.13.0",
    "pinia": "^2.0.32",
    "vue": "^3.2.47",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rushstack/eslint-patch": "^1.2.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.14.2",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^7.1.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^11.0.2",
    "@vue/tsconfig": "^0.1.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "eslint": "^8.34.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.9.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "prettier": "^2.8.4",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.2.0",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.2.0"
  }
}
```

Please enlighten me about the nature of failure of the abovementioned code on any mobile device.

I have tried using onMounted, onUpdated hooks, storeToRefs from pinia, but looks like the select element itself has some problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was actually in the way I tried to use < select > with Vue v-for directive. V-model and, highly likely, similar operators don't work inside < option > tags and have to be used inside < select > itself. Strangely, however, that the whole thing was working on desktop and not throwing any error, even the case is [well-documented](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#v-for-on-template).

Nevertheless, this is the final code. Hope it will help someone with a similar problem.

1. I had to add a ref lang to my NavigationLanguageSelect.vue

```
import { ref } from 'vue'

const lang = ref(localStorage.getItem('lang') || navigator.language.slice(0, 2))
```

2. I used v-model to reference `lang` with the selected option and emit lang on change:

```
    <select
      @change="emit('changeLang', lang)"
      v-model="lang"
      class="p-1 text-sm rounded-lg text-gray-700"
    >
      <option class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100" disabled>
        {{ currentFlag }} {{ currentText }}
      </option>
      <option
        class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100"
        v-for="language in langs"
        :key="language.text"
        :value="language.value"
      >
        {{ language.flag }} {{ language.text }}
      </option>
    </select>
```